# how to design a server for variable size messages

Tags: c, network-programming

I want some feedback or suggestion on how to design a server that handles variable size messages.

to simplify the answer lets assume:

single thread epoll() based

the protocol is: data-size + data

data is stored on a ringbuffer

the read code, with some simplification for clarity, looks like this:

```
    if (client->readable) {
        if (client->remaining > 0) {
            /* SIMPLIFIED FOR CLARITY - assume we are always able to read 1+ bytes */
            rd = read(client->sock, client->buffer, client->remaining);
            client->buffer += rd;
            client->remaining -= rd;
        } else {
            /* SIMPLIFIED FOR CLARITY - assume we are always able to read 4 bytes */
            read(client->sock, &(client->remaining), 4);
            client->buffer = acquire_ringbuf_slot(client->remaining);
        }
    }
```

please, do not focus on the 4 byte. just assume we have the data size in the beginning compressed or not does not make difference for this discussion.

now, the question is: what is the best way to do the above?

assume both small "data", few bytes and large data MBs

how can we reduce the number of read() calls? e.g. in case we have 4 message of 16 bytes on the stream, it seems a waste doing 8 calls to read().

are there better alternatives to this design?

Comment: IMO, if you are dealing with buffered I/O. The number of calls to read does not matter much. The read() will just go to the buffer and fetch (or wait for) the number of bytes and return.

Comment: I trust there is error-checking in the real code. `rd` can be zero, which means one thing, or -1, which means another, or positive, which means a third.

Comment: let me edit, and add the 3rd SIMPLIFIED FOR CLARITY, since it does not seems to be clear...

Answer (score 1):

PART of the solution depends on the transport layer protocol you use.
I assume you are using TCP which provides connection oriented and reliable communication.
From your code I assume you understand TCP is a stream-oriented protocol
(So when a client sends a piece of data, that data is stored in the socket send buffer and TCP may use one or more TCP segments to convey it to the other end (server)).

So the code, looks very good so far (considering you have error checks and other things in the real code).

Now for your questions, I give you my responses, what I think is best based on my experience (but there could be better solutions):

1-This is a solution with challenges similar to how an OS manages memory, dealing with fragmentation. 
For handling different message sizes, you have to understand there are always trade-offs depending on your performance goals.
One solution to improve memory utilization and parallelization is to have a list of free buffer chunks of certain size, say 4KB. 
You will retrieve as many as you need for storing your received message. In the last one you will have unused data. You play with internal fragmentation.
The drawback could be when you need to apply certain type of processing (maybe a visitor pattern) on the message, like parsing/routing/transformation/etc. It will be more complex and less efficient than a case of a huge buffer of contiguous memory. On the other side, the drawback of a huge buffer is much less efficient memory utilization, memory bottlenecks, and less parallelization. 
You can implement something smarter in the middle (think about chunks that could also be contiguous whenever available). Always depending on your goals. Something useful is to implement an abstraction over the fragmented memory so that every function (or visitor) that is applied works as it were dealing with contiguous memory.
If you use these chunks, when the message was processed and dropped/forwarded/eaten/whatever, you return the unused chunks to the list of free chunks.

2-The number of read calls will depend on how fast TCP conveys the data from client to server. Remember this is stream oriented and you don't have much control over it. Of course, I'm assuming you try to read the max possible (remaining) data in each read.
If you use the chunks I mentioned above the max data to read will also depend on the chunk size.
Something you can do at TCP layer is to increase the server receive buffer. Thus, it can receive more data even when server cannot read it fast enough.

3-The ring buffer is OK, if you used chunked, the ring buffer should provide the abstraction. But I don't know why you need a ring buffer. 
I like ring buffers because there is a way of implementing producer-consumer synchronization without locking (Linux Kernel uses this for moving packets from L2 to IP layer) but I don't know if that's your goal.

To pass messages to other components and/or upper-layers you could also use ring buffers of pointers to messages.

Answer (score -1):

A better design may be as follows:

1. Set up your user-space socket read buffer to be the same size as the kernel socket buffer. If your user-space socket read buffer is smaller, then you would need more than one `read` syscall to read the kernel buffer. If your user-space buffer is bigger, then the extra space is wasted.
2. Your read function should only read as much data as possible in one `read` syscall. This function must not know anything about the protocol. This way you do not need to re-implement this function for different wire formats.
3. When your read function has read into the user-space buffer it should call a callback passing the iterators to the data available in the buffer. That callback is a parser function that should extract all available complete messages and pass these messages to another higher-level callback. Upon return the parser function should return the number of bytes consumed, so that these bytes can be discarded from the user-space socket buffer.

Comment: isn't this just moving the problem from "too many read()" to "too many memcpy()"? assume I still have to copy the data to the ringbuffer

Comment: @user5042034 Hmm, not sure what you mean. Ideally, you should only have one copy - from the kernel to the user-space and your userspace buffer should be a ringbuffer.

Comment: assume the ringbuffer is shared between all client/messages. client-1 is readable but the available data is 3 byte, not enough to identify the space required to reserve on the ringbuf. then client-2 is readable.. if you write directly to the ringbuf you end up with [client-1 3byte][client-2][client-1 other bytes]. so, the ringbuf does not contains a set of messages but just a set of bytes that you have to reconstruct somehow

Comment: @user5042034 What all clients? Not sure I follow you.

Comment: the server should be able to handle multiple clients. each client send messages. the messages are added to the ringbuf. the ringbuf should look like [msg1, msg2, msg3, ...] the ringbuf does not contain only messages from one client, but all the clients append to the same ringbuf

Comment: @user5042034 We were talking about receiving messages from one socket. It does not matter how those messages were sent.

Comment: you have one socket per client, the important part of the snippet is acquire_ringbuf_slot() where the client is able to reserve the buffer and then push directly on it. if you fetch a larger chunk then you have to memcpy on the ringbuf to have the same result as the code above

Comment: @user5042034 I was not clear, but it is one user-space buffer per one socket.